# Unable to Restart the SQL server Agent from SSCM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

In my machine SQL Server Agent is not expandable with a label (Agent XPs disabled). In this case I run this code to enable it.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE  
GO
```

Then Restart the Agent on SQL server Configuration Manager, it throws this error:

> The Request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details

When I checked the Windows event log, I saw this error:

> Failed to initialize SQL Agent log, The system cannot find the path specified.

What is the resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we identified it was a permissions issue via the comments, I would suggest you adjust the account running the SQL Agent service to something different if this is a server.  [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/select-an-account-for-the-sql-server-agent-service) does a great job to outline the permissions needed for the SQL Agent service account.  That article also highlights a few pitfalls regarding some minimal permission grants you want to do so users outside of the sysadmin role can properly utilize Proxy accounts, etc.

If it's your local PC, it likely doesn't matter that you adjust this account nearly as much since that service isn't configured for automatic startup by default.

Glad you got it sorted.